# Как вывести две цены на woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

У товаров есть вариации (блок комплектация станка), поэтому я полагаю что 
выбор цены не может быть реализован через вариации. 
Как сделать выбор цены нажатием на табы? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это как раз вариативный товар

Comment: @SeVlad в этом и дело, а цены должны выбираться вне зависимости от вариаций

Comment: Что значит "цены должны выбираться вне зависимости от вариаций"? Для каждого варианта можно задать свою цену.

Comment: @SeVlad а вторую цену как указать тогда

Comment: Какую вторую? Задаёшь каждой вариации свою цену и всё. Вариация=вариант. Т.е. это по сути отдельный товар _в составе вариантивного_ со своими хар-ками: ценой, комплектацией (набором атрибутов), артикулом и тп. А вариативный товар - это можно сказать виртуальная сущность, объединяющая варианты в одной карточке.